# Using ZeroMQ in windows java binding in netbeans

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, zeromq

Hallllooooo Buddies,

I want to use zeromq library in a socket programming project, and I have read about this in some articles like [This](http://zeromq.org/area:download) and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11455588/how-to-run-zeromq-with-java) I want to use zero mq in netbeans IDE and windows. would you please help me  to know about the installation ?